# Convert wstring to const *char in c++

Tags: c++

I have got a wstring and I want to convert it to const char in order to write it with the write function of fstream library. What I tried to do is the following:

```
std::ofstream out("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
char mbstr[11];
std::wcstombs(mbstr, strValue.c_str(), 11); //strValue my wstring
out.write(mbstr, 11);
... // i have got another four wstring.
```

I am not sure what I did, however the result is a text file is weird:

```
0.100693 ÌÌ0.000000 ÌÌ0.004094 ÌÌ0.360069 ÌÌ0.086034
```

Any idea how can I write properly my wstring in the file?

Comment: Answer yourself a couple of questions first. What type is `strValue`? (You *say* it's `wstring`, but how could *we* be certain?) `wstring` is `basic_string<wchar_t>`. Is your `wchar_t` two or four bytes (Windows / Unix)? What is your current locale? (Because `wcstombs` is locale-dependent.) What encoding does the data in `strValue` use? Is it the same as indicated by your locale? [Why are you not using ICU?](http://www.icu-project.org)

Comment: What locale do you use? What's the content of the input string? What output did you expect?

Comment: `std::wofstream out("test.txt", .....);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're converting correctly, but you're not writing correctly. Just do `out << mbstr;`. Currently you're writing the 11 bytes in the array no matter what's in there, and the strange characters you see are the random junk after the area written by `wcstombs`.

Of course, a better way might be to use a `wofstream` in the first place. Then you can simply insert your wide string directly.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you could just use [wstring_convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert)

```
inline std::wstring ConvertEncoding(const std::string& normalString)
{
     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
     return convert.from_bytes(normalString);
}

inline std::string ConvertEncodingBack(const std::wstring& wideString)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes(wideString);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
std::ofstream out("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
std::string normalString = ConvertEncodingBack(strValue);
```

Comment: The question is not tagged `c++11`

Comment: The question isn't, but it is still a good option for whoever does use it

Comment: @GargAnkit: The current version of the C++ standard is C++14. I think the time where availability of C++11 features needed to be flagged explicitly is past.

Comment: @DevSolar I so wish that was practically true!

Comment: Lets assume that most developers use default compilers (because the don't know better). So, recent ubuntu versions have gcc 4.4, which has c++11. But C++14 is only available from gcc 4.8 (And i'm pretty sure it doesn't have all the features yet). And in windows - Vs2010 - C++0x , Vs2012 - C++11 (not fully supported) Vs2013 - more C++11 features .. Vs2015 - some c++14 features

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: That logic would limit us to C89 because Microsoft never actually bothered to make their compiler C99 compliant. I refuse to accept that. ;-)